# sync a group of async functions

Tags: swift, grand-central-dispatch, swift5, dispatch-queue

I have some functions to async to each other so, they starts same time but they also sync to others, I built that structure but it looks so dirty, I wanted to ask maybe there is another way to do this.

```
func doCalc() {
    let x = 100
    let y = x*x
    _ = y/x
}

func performCalculation(_ iterations: Int, tag: String) {
    let start = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    for _ in 0 ..< iterations {
        doCalc()
    }
    let end = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    print("time for \(tag):\(start) ||||| \(end)")
}

let cqueue = DispatchQueue(label: "cqueue", attributes:.concurrent)

cqueue.async {
    performCalculation(100000, tag: "async1")
}
cqueue.async {
    performCalculation(1000, tag: "async2")
}

cqueue.async(flags: .barrier) {}

    cqueue.async {
        performCalculation(1000, tag: "async3")
}
    cqueue.async {
        performCalculation(12300, tag: "async4")
}
```

Here we have 4 functions async1-async2 are async to each other but sync to async3-async4, and async3-async4 are also async to each other.

so result is

```
time for async2:633770666.148861 ||||| 633770666.20431
time for async1:633770666.148816 ||||| 633770667.26695
time for async3:633770667.267107 ||||| 633770667.280905
time for async4:633770667.267113 ||||| 633770667.39507
```

But this looks so dirty in a real project, if I have several functions async and sync to each other.
Is there a way to group them? like

```
cqueue.sync{
// func4-5-6 starts after func 1-2-3 ends
    cqueue.async{
    // all functions are running concurrently in different threads
        func1
        func2
        func3
    }
    cqueue.async{
    // all functions are running concurrently in different threads
        func4
        func5
        func6
    }

}
```

Comment: I think it is not necessary to add async3 and async4 inside the body of barrier task. You can simply add an empty body barrier task to separate the execution of (async1, async2) and (async3, async4): `cqueue.async(flags: .barrier) {}`. This way the code will look less messy.

Comment: thank you, I applied your advice it is little bit improved :)

Comment: The correct design depends upon so many different factors and your attempt to keep it generic makes it impossible for us to advise you well. E.g. in your second sample of “1/2/3 first, then 4/5/6”, is it really a max of three things at a time? If the number of things might be arbitrarily large, then that calls for a very different solution than if there are only a max of 3 running concurrently. Also, let’s say that 1 and 2 have finished, but 3 is really taking a long time. Do you really want 4/5/6 to wait, leaving most of the cores in the device sitting idle, waiting for 3?

Comment: In short, the way you’ve described it, I disagree with the others and would stick w barriers (but I’d lose the `sync` calls). Of if you’re really trying to maximize efficiency for massively parallel task while avoiding thread explosion, then it begs for `concurrentPerform`. But if any of these tasks, themselves, are asynchronous operations, or if you’re dealing with complicated dependencies then maybe asynchronous `Operation` subclass with `isFinished` and `isExecuting` KVO and inter-operation dependencies makes sense.

Comment: @Rob you are right actually, I should have described the situation better. I am saving my JSON data in my app folder as binary, after URL request. So first I have URLrequest then taking that request by closure then I have savetofolder functions called in this closure. After saving is completed I want to Load my data from local folder. So I isolate my web service and application. I didn't want to use closure to avoid chains and also didn't want to use Obj C KVO, Apple says they may discontinue to support in future.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [DispatchGroup](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchgroup) in order to perform asynchronous work and be notified when tasks have finished executing.
You will need to specify to the `DispatchGroup` every time a task start (`.enter()`) and when it ends (`leave()`).

Thus, if you want ‘async3’ and ‘async4’ to be executed asynchronously after the execution of `async1` and `async2` you could proceed like so:

```swift
func performCalculations {
    group.enter()
    cqueue.async {
        performCalculation(100000, tag: "async1")
        group.leave()
    }

    group.enter()
    cqueue.async {
        performCalculation(1000, tag: "async2")
        group.leave()
    }

    group.notify(queue: .global()) {
        cqueue.async {
            performCalculation(1000, tag: "async3")
        }
        cqueue.async {
            performCalculation(12300, tag: "async4")
        }
    }
}
```

Alternatively, you could use an [OperationQueue](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/operationqueue) which is a powerful tool that allows to define dependencies between tasks but they are more complex and require more work to handle asynchronous behaviors.

```swift
final class AsyncOperation: Operation { ... }

let queue = OperationQueue()
let task1 = AsyncOperation(queue: cqueue) {
    performCalculation(100000, tag: "async1")
}
let task2 = AsyncOperation(queue: cqueue) {
    performCalculation(1000, tag: "async2")
}
// task2 is not considered ready to execute until task1 is finished.
task2.addDependency(task1)
queue.addOperations([task1, task2], waitUntilFinished: true))
```